# EF - Load properties of child property with single .Include() possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF connected to SQL Server (C#). I am able to get my desired list of results with the following code:

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var list = context.Jobs
        .Include(a => a.JobDetails)
        .Include(a => a.Shifts.Select(b => b.ShiftDetails.Select(c => c.FirstProperty))) // !!
        .Include(a => a.Shifts.Select(b => b.ShiftDetails.Select(c => c.SecondProperty))) // !!
        .Include(a => a.Shifts.Select(b => b.ShiftDetails.Select(c => c.ThirdProperty))) // !!
        .Include(a => a.Shifts.Select(b => b.ShiftDetails.Select(c => c.FourthProperty))) // !!
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Here, the single include per property up to the third level seems dubious. Is there any way to simplify it, something along the lines of:

```
.Include(a => a.Shifts.Select(b => b.ShiftDetails).Select(c => c.FirstProperty, c.SecondProperty, c.ThirdProperty)...
```

and so on?

Comment: What is `FirstProperty` and so on?

Comment: @CodingYoshi Properties of ShiftDetails, please see the edit if it is any clearer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put down two solutions. `Solution 1` is relevant to what you are trying to achieve and `Solution 2` is a more optimized way of doing things given you have designed a correct Database schema

**Solution 1**

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var list = context.Jobs
        .Include(a => a.JobDetails)
        .Include(a => a.Shifts.Select(b => b.ShiftDetails.Select(c => new {c.FirstProperty,c.SecondProperty,c.ThirdProperty,c.FourthProperty})))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    var list = context.Jobs
        .Include(a => a.JobDetails)
        .Include(a => a.Shifts)
        .Include(a => a.ShiftDetails)
        .Select(a => new {a.ShiftDetails.FirstProperty, a.ShiftDetails.SecondProperty,a.ShiftDetails.ThirdProperty,a.ShiftDetails.FourthProperty})
        .ToListAsync();
}
```